# FindTabByUrl on tabs nested within another tab using Telerik

Tags: tabs, telerik, nested

I have a RadTabStrip being used as a menu (the tabs act as links), some tabs when clicked open a sub-menu for related links.

I have the following code to highlight the current tab being visited:

**Master Page Code-behind**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            RadTabStrip tabControl = FindControl("radTabMenu"); //Pseudo
            RadTab currentTab = tabControl.FindTabByUrl(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
            if (currentTab != null) currentTab.Selected = true;
    }
```

**Master Page**

```
 <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="radTabMenu" runat="server">
     <Tabs>
         <telerik:RadTab Text="Home" NavigateUrl="~/" />  <!-- Loads Default.aspx -->
         <telerik:RadTab Text="Menu Item" NavigateUrl="~/MenuItem.aspx" />
         <telerik:RadTab Text="Top Level Nav">
             <Tabs>
                 <telerik:RadTab Text="Lower Menu Item 1" />
                 <telerik:RadTab Text="Lower Menu Item 2" NavigateUrl="~/Location/Page.aspx" />
             </Tabs>
         </telerik:RadTab>
     </Tabs>
 </telerik:RadTabStrip>
```

On page load if I have clicked Menu Item tab to load MenuItem page, the RadTabs correctly highlights the tab.  However, I'm not sure how to go about making sure the sub-tab gets highlighted correctly.

I'm trying this, but I'm a little stuck:

```
            RadTabStrip tabControl = FindControl("radTabMenu"); //Pseudo
            RadTab currentTab = tabControl.FindTabByUrl(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
            if (currentTab != null)
                currentTab.Selected = true;
            else
            {
                string dir = Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.Path, UriFormat.SafeUnescaped);
                currentTab = tabControl.FindTabByValue(dir);

                if (currentTab != null)
                    //Trying to findByUrl isn't possible here because the parent tab doesn't have that method.
            }
```

Is there a good alternative to finding by URL, or a faster method overall of reaching the parent and sub-tabs?

*EDIT: Adding a picture to clarify what I'm trying to achieve after page navigation*

[image: Lower Menu Item 2 is highlighted after being clicked on, and (theoretical) page /TopLevelNav/LowerMenuItem2.aspx is loaded]

Comment: Does your Lower Menu Item 1 have a NavigateUrl at all?

Comment: Currently, no.  Does every tab have to have a NavigateUrl?

Comment: No, it does not. So, your problem arise only when a tab does not have a navigateUrl, correct?

Comment: No.  I cannot access the method "FindTabByUrl" on  TopLevelNav's nested tabs, so I can't even use NavigateUrl to highlight either of them.

Answer (score 0):

The FindTabBy* methods are available at either RadTabStrip or RadTabCollection level. 
That's why, once you find the parent tab you were not able to invoke the FindTabBy* method on it, because you need to invoke the method on its .Tabs property instead.

See an example below:

```
 var parent = radTabMenu.FindTabByText("Top Level Nav");
 parent.Selected = true;

 var child = parent.Tabs.FindTabByText("Lower Menu Item 1");
 child.Selected = true;
```

Comment: I suppose if I hard-coded the tab text name into each .aspx page I load this would work.

The issue here is that I (want to) select tabs relative to URL.  Accessing by URL gives me the flexibility of ignoring the structure of tabs, so doing my solution this way would give me the complete opposite.

Comment: True, but how do you find a tab by URL, if the tab does not have a URL in the first place?

Comment: I think there's confusion here.  It does have a url:
     <telerik:RadTab Text="Lower Menu Item 2" NavigateUrl="~/Location/Page.aspx" />

Comment: Did you want to highlight the Lower Menu Item 2 then? If so, you can use the FindTabByUrl method on the Tabs collection of the parent tab (see my answer). In my code it uses FindTabByText, but you can equally use FindTabByUrl instead.

Comment: You are correct, I could still use FindTabByURL.

I also found the solution to opening the parent tabs up.  Which turned out to be a little too obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this, well after having my team decide to remove nested tab menus, I found that the tabs would be selected by URL.

My issue was that the parent tab wouldn't open and be selected, but digging through documentation led me to use `tab.Select Parents()` which goes up the hierarchy selecting all parents that lead to the current selected tab.

It seems super obvious now that I've found it.